# Get type implementors using .NET microsoft dependency injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, backgroundworker

I have i case where I need to get the type implementors registered in container to use them in BackgroundService.

```
public abstract class ServiceRunner
{
    public abstract Task RunAsync(CancellationToken token);
}

public class ServiceRunner<TService> : ServiceRunner
    where TService : IService
{

    ServiceRunner(/*ctor parameters*/)
    {
        ...
    }

    //class logic implementation

    public override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        ...
    }            
 }
```

So I'd like to get the ServiceRunner implementors, registered in container to run them all in BackgroundService worker.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ScpWorker(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = provider;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var services = _serviceProvider.GetServiceImplementors<ServiceRunner>(); //Have no idea how to implement this method

        var tasks = services.Select(s => s.RunAsync(stoppingToken));

        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do you need get all your services that they are implementing "ServiceRunner"?

Comment: No, i need the only registered in container by some config logic

Comment: so I've gotten that you've registered some "Implemented object of ServiceRunner" in the container, for example, you have 6 implements but you've registered 3 of them, and you need to get all these 3 objects and use them? am I right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely)

Answer (score 3):

In this case for my opinion you could register all specific generic classes just as `ServiceRunner`

```cs
// the place you register your dependencies
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceRunner, ServiceRunnerA>();
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceRunner, ServiceRunnerB>();
```

Or if you want to access to a specific `ServiceRunner<T>` in some logic:

```cs
// the place you register your dependencies
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceRunner<ServiceA>, ServiceRunnerA>();
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceRunner<ServiceB>, ServiceRunnerB>();
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceRunner>(s => s.Resolve<ServiceRunner<ServiceA>>());
    services.AddSingleton<ServiceRunner>(s => s.Resolve<ServiceRunner<ServiceB>>());
```

And then add `IEnumerable<ServiceRunner>` argument to the `Worker` constructor:

```cs
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ServiceRunner> _serviceRunners;

    public Worker(IEnumerable<ServiceRunner> serviceRunners)
    {
        _serviceRunners = serviceRunners;
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        if(_serviceRunners == null || _serviceRunners.Count() == 0)
        {
            // log warning or throw an exception here
        }
        var tasks = _serviceRunners.Select(s => s.RunAsync(stoppingToken));

        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It works. I have done something like that with [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77976412/12566464)

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you can get all your objects in the container

```
var allServiceRunners = _serviceProvider.GetServices<YourType>();
```

so you can use them

Comment: Thansk a lot! It really works but only in casses when I register the implementers like services.AddSingleton<ServiceRunner,ServiceRunner<ServiceA>>(); But is there way to get the implementers if I register them this way services.AddSingleton<ServiceRunner<ServiceA>(); ?

Comment: @AlexanderZhyshkevich Thanks for checking and responding, I think you need a base of your objects to get them from the service provider, but I will check it for you, and if I get the answer I will write it to you

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement your method something like this, it goes through all registered services and filters the implementations of the `ServiceRunner<TService>` and returns as a collection of ServiceRunner

```
public static IEnumerable<ServiceRunner> GetServiceImplementors<TService>(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var serviceType = typeof(TService);
    var serviceRunnerType = typeof(ServiceRunner<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType);
    var serviceRunners = serviceProvider.GetServices(serviceRunnerType);
    return serviceRunners.Cast<ServiceRunner>();
}
```

Comment: It should work but in my case Worker doesn't know registered ServiceRunner implementor types to use them as generic parameter in your approach